# ng-model data not getting when saving the data

Tags: angularjs

here save the ng-model is newattendance saving to database. "newattendance._id" is not taken as a ng-model.how to make it "newattendance._id" is ng-model

```
 <select class="form-control" ng-options="item.empcode as item.empcode for item in totemplist" ng-model="item.empcode">
                </select>
<input type="text" ng-repeat="newattendance in totemplist" ng-model="newattendance._id" ng-show="item.empcode ==newattendance.empcode" style="width:200px;" ><br>
<input placeholder="Enter Attendacne Date" ng-model="newattendance.doa">

<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="checkOut()">checkOut</button>
```

Controller

```
EmpMasterController.controller("AttendanceController", ['$scope', 'AttendanceFactory',"EmpAddService", function($scope, AttendanceFactory,EmpAddService){
$scope.newattendance={};
$scope.totemplist=EmpAddService.getAllEmpAddItems();
console.log($scope.totemplist);
$scope.checkIn = function(){
    AttendanceFactory.addAttendance($scope.newattendance);
    $scope.newattendance = {}
}   
$scope.getAllAttendance = function(){

     console.log("$$$$$"+$scope.newattendance._id)
     $scope.attendancedetails =AttendanceFactory.getAllAttendance($scope.newattendance._id);

}
```

}])

Factory

```
EmpFactModule.factory("AttendanceFactory", function($resource, RES_URL){
var attendanceResource = $resource(RES_URL+"attandence/:id/:attid", 
                    {"id": "@id", "attid": "@attid"}, {update: {method: "PUT"}})
var attendanceDetails;
return {
    addAttendance: function(newattendance){
        console.log("..1.. " + newattendance._id)
        attendanceResource.save({"id":newattendance._id}, newattendance, function(data){
            console.log("Add Success ")
        }, function(data, status){
            console.log("Add Failed*****");
        })
    },
    getAllAttendance: function(_id){
        console.log("..@.. " + _id)
        attendanceDetails = attendanceResource.query({"id": _id});
        return attendanceDetails;
    },


}
})
```

please help me how make it as ng-model and how to save this...

Comment: Please add your complete code.

Answer (score 0):

I've create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oronbdd/42vr9cpp/2/) for you which hopefully will help you understand the 2 way binding in angular.

you dont need to pass the `newattendance` object to the check-out function, it is already saved on the `scope`.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="formValidation">
    <div>
      <div>
        <span>User Name</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="John" ng-model="newattendance._id">
        <span>
          <button ng-click="submit()">
            check out
          </button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <pre>{{newattendance._id}}</pre>

  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('formValidation', function($scope) {

  $scope.submit=function(){
    var formPost = {
      "Username":$scope.newattendance._id
    };
    console.log(formPost);
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. i know this two way binding. my problem is ng-show with ng-model is notworking. i am getting data from select options and bind the data to the input box using ng-show. but ng-model is not binding newattendance._id

Comment: Please provide the response json, and I will update my answer accordinly

Comment: according to api newattendance._id is must send with ng-model. check the factory while saving.    response was 404 error. i send the newattendance._id as manual its working.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand. please provide the response from the factory. I need the json object so I will be able to help you. In addition try to create a JSFiddle with working code.